# How can i view the process running on vagrant from my browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox, vagrant, windows-8.1

I have installed Vagrant and Virtualbox-4.3 on my Ubuntu system and windows 8 system and i want to run the ruby on rails project in the vagrant. How can i tunnel the project through the browser which in my machine.

`If i run the rails project on port 3000 on vagrant. how can i see the result from my browser?`
  Do let me know to tunnel the result through the browser and to set the static ip for vagrant. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, the first doesn't require any setup but, it will change every time that you start up your vagrant box.

1. ssh into you box (`vagrant ssh`)
2. Get the IP address of the box (`ifconfig`)
3. Open your web browser and go to <ip_address>:3000

A better way to do this is to specify a [forwarded port](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html). This way, you can always access your app in the same way. Add the `config.vm.network` network line like so,

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
end
```

After adding that line, you'll need to reboot the box. You can do this by running `vagrant reload`. Once that process finishes, start up your app again. You will now be able to connect to your app by going to `http://127.0.0.1:3000`